# Uninstall a program with PowerShell or VBScript

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I tried using this code in this thread: [How can I uninstall an application using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113542/how-can-i-uninstall-an-application-using-powershell)

But it doesn't uninstall the product.

I just get this back:

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ReturnValue      : 1603
```

Any ideas? Can I do this with VB easier? I need to uninstall a .exe then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that you need to disable McAfee before uninstalling. So I will need to devise a workaround for this, but the script does work as is.