# How to extract ProductCode from msi package?

Tags: windows-installer

How to extract ProductCode from msi package? I want to use it later to uninstall msi via msiexec as described [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/msiexec.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: this is in VB script but could give some ideas: http://leereid.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/vbscript-get-msi-productcode/

Comment: Orca.exe is your friend if you'd like to do this manually

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113542/how-can-i-uninstall-an-application-using-powershell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of dozens of ways to do it.  What programming languages do you currently use and/or comfortable with?

Take a look at

[Execute SQL Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You could use WiRunSQL.vbs ( provided in the Platform SDK ) to run the command:

```
cscript /nologo WiRunSQL.vbs FOO.msi "SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductCode'"
```

Comment: I want to do it from command line. The best way is to run some tool or at least VB script which will do the job. Standalone tool is preferable.

Comment: Let's pretend I had GetProductCode.exe FOO.MSI  ... what would you want it to do?  Set an environment variable?  Output to the console?  I'm trying to understand the bigger picture so I can suggest something.

Comment: I would want it to output to console. Then I would save output and pass it to msiexec in this way: cmd /c msiexec /x {SOME_PRODUCT_CODE} /q no matter how. I only need some easy way to obtain ProductCode.

Comment: I updated my answer to do what you want but I am a little confused why you want to get the PC and /x PC when you could just say /x FOO.msi

Comment: In my case FOO.msi can be up to 300Mb so it takes some time to load it. With PC I can immediately start uninstall process without loading msi. Thanks for help, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Realize that some (mostly poorly written) installers can end up requiring access to the 300MB MSI during uninstall.

Comment: @Christopher Painter: Some installers (like one I'm testing) give a "Another version is already installed" message if you `msiexec /u` them. So, I personally would be interested in one of your remaining 11 solutions which a) don't give that error b) ideally dont require arbitrary bits of arbitrary SDKs.

Comment: @RubenBartelink What language?

Comment: Ideally a .NET one, e.g., PowerShell, CSharp, ScriptCS

Comment: Windows Installer XML (WiX) has an MSI SDK called Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF). DTF includes an MSI interop library called Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller which is the gold standard.  If you don't want any dependencies then take a look at P/Invoke.Net or the source code to said assembly for how to query MSI's.

Comment: +1 Thanks for that detail (only seeing now due to absence of atting). Now I need to cross my fingers that my interest in this topic doesn't get retriggered :P

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Powershell function that I use when generating MSI-based Chocolatey packages at work, to detect if our internal package is installing a program that was already installed via other means:

```
function Get-MsiProductCode {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateScript({$_ | Test-Path -PathType Leaf})]
        [string]$Path
    )

    function Get-Property ( $Object, $PropertyName, [object[]]$ArgumentList ) {
        return $Object.GetType().InvokeMember($PropertyName, 'Public, Instance, GetProperty', $null, $Object, $ArgumentList)
    }

    function Invoke-Method ( $Object, $MethodName, $ArgumentList ) {
        return $Object.GetType().InvokeMember( $MethodName, 'Public, Instance, InvokeMethod', $null, $Object, $ArgumentList )
    }

    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

    #http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369432(v=vs.85).aspx
    $msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly = 0
    $Installer = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer

    $Database = Invoke-Method $Installer OpenDatabase $Path, $msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly

    $View = Invoke-Method $Database OpenView "SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property='ProductCode'"

    [void]( Invoke-Method $View Execute )

    $Record = Invoke-Method $View Fetch
    if ( $Record ) {
        Get-Property $Record StringData 1
    }

    [void]( Invoke-Method $View Close @() )
    Remove-Variable -Name Record, View, Database, Installer
}
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve a similar effect by doing the following in PowerShell based on the installed programs:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Vendor LIKE 'The Company%' AND Name LIKE '%The Product%'" | %{ 
    Write-Host "Uninstalling $($_.IdentifyingNumber)"
    $_.Uninstall() 
}
```

(Obv the tighter the query, the quicker it will run - the LIKE above is very expensive)

Or you could apply [the general technique in here](http://leereid.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/vbscript-get-msi-productcode/) on your stack.

Comment: Win32_Product queries will never run quickly because frankly the MSI WMI provider is horribly written.  This also assumes that the MSI he wants the ProductCode for is installed on the system.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Fair enough. To be honest I'm having difficulty recalling where I needed this and/or what solution I actually applied in the end :)

Comment: Another warning against using `Win32_Product`, this can trigger MSI repairs unintentionally.