# Powershell Get MSI file GUID

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, guid

In order to find an installed MSI file **GUID** in a remote VM - I'm using the following command inside of `Invoke-Command`: 
`Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Application Name"}`
This command shows in it's output an identifier number. 
I know, I should add one more thing to this command in order to get only the GUID but I don't know how...

Now, I need to compare between this GUID to a GUID of a new MSI file I got for an installation.

This mean that: 
if the GUID of the new file is older - I'll do nothing 
if the GUID of the new file is equal - I'll do nothing 
if the GUID of the new file is newer - I'll do an upgrade OR uninstall-install process...

So, In order to compare between the installed MSI's GUID and a new MSI file's GUID: 
What will be the exact **PowerShell** command to find the GUID of the **new MSI file**?

Comment: If you want to upgrade our application there is a means to do so built into MSI. It is called [major upgrades](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23396011/129130). Here is [more on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50552215/129130).

Comment: Using Powershell to retrieve product code, different methods: 1) [Run MSI session](https://adamrushuk.github.io/get-product-id-guid-directly-from-msi-file/), 2) [Open MSI database file](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskGreg/comments/2hxbw6/powershell_get_product_code_from_msi_file/). I don't use Powershell much. I think it is a bit "high line noise".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a [Carbon](http://get-carbon.org/) library both in the remote VM and in my pc in "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules"
I then execute the following Command:

```
[string] $newMSIProductCode = (Get-CMsi -Path "C:\appName.msi").ProductVersion
[string] $newMSIProductCodeGUID = (Get-CMsi -Path "C:\appName.msi").ProductCode.Guid
$newMSIProductCode = $newMSIProductCode -replace '\.',''


Enter-PSSession -Computer $computer -Credential $credentials
Invoke-Command -Computer $computer -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {

   [string] $installedMSIProductCode = (Get-CProgramInstallInfo -Name "app name").DisplayVersion
   $installedMSIProductCodeGUID = (Get-CProgramInstallInfo -Name "app name").ProductCode.Guid
   [long] $installedMSIProductCode = $installedMSIProductCode -replace '\.',''

   if ($Using:$newMSIProductCodeGUID -gt $installedR10ServerBuildProductCode)
   {
      //TO-DO 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to find the product GUID of an MSI that is not currently installed? I hope that is a correct understanding of what you ask. If you need to automatically get the product GUID from code, [that is also possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5005737/129130). There is a [full, standalone VBScript](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/MSI%20Find%20Product%20Code.vbs) here which you can drag-and-drop an MSI file onto to retrieve the product code.

You can find the product code by opening the MSI with a suitable viewer - for example **`Orca`**, the Microsoft SDK tool for MSI packages. If you have Visual Studio installed, try searching for **`Orca-x86_en-us.msi`** - under **`Program Files (x86)`** - and install it. Then find Orca in the start menu. You can also right click MSI files to open them with Orca - just select: **`"Edit with Orca"`**. Then you can **find the product GUID in the Property table.**

[image: Orca]

Here is an answer on the topic of MSI viewers (several alternatives, but Orca is the best overall): [How can I compare the content of two (or more) MSI files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546)

---

There is a Powershell module for MSI:
https://github.com/heaths/psmsi

---

***Links:***

- [How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup)
- [**Finding the Product Code with Orca**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22862283/129130)