# Avoid confirmation box in MsiExec uninstall

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I need to run the msiexec uninstall from my code:

```
MsiExec.exe /I{A52EEC0E-D0B7-4345-A0FF-574804C7B78A}
```

But this is asking for a confirmation (Yes/No). How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`msiexec /quiet` will avoid the userinteraction

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `/passive` switch to do this.

`MsiExec.exe /I{A52EEC0E-D0B7-4345-A0FF-574804C7B78A} /passive`

If you want to completely hide the UI, use the `/quiet` switch instead of `/passive`.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `/qn` flags to your command line. `/q` is quiet mode and `n` is a flag for `/q` that suppresses all user interface.

With these flags added, the complete command would be:

```
MsiExec.exe /qn /I{A52EEC0E-D0B7-4345-A0FF-574804C7B78A}
```

Comment: Not fully correct. Yes, "/qn" is one of the possible parameters here. To give the full story here to all the answers: /qn and /q are equivalent- and /quiet is the same too. This is the silent variant. The second, unattended variant (with progress bar, but without asking or other modal boxes) is /qb or the equivalent /passive. All parameters solve the mentioned problem.

Comment: Of course there are more like /qb+ /qn+ or the variants with ("!") which is hiding the cancel button during progress (/qb+! /qb-!).