# How to uninstall any application using python or (and) ruby

Tags: python, ruby, windows

I didn't find any helpful topics over the webs by this question.
These all about how to uninstall python or uninstall ruby but there are no information about the #{TOPIC}.

The main problem is that I used other interesting [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113542/how-can-i-uninstall-an-application-using-powershell) to try to uninstall an application using PowerShell script but all that didn't help me because that script with several variants of -Query "query" never finds my application even by unrigorous mask like '%APPL_NAME%' or by version number.

Seems like table Win32_Product filled uncorrectly or any function works bad now. 
Moreover, for me, it's not so cool to use PowerShell if I have such flexible languages.

So i'm interested in ways how to uninstall any program through the ruby or python.

Thank you for any ideas :-)

**Edit**:
Let's I ask the question to another way. How to uninstall ordinary program which was installed thruogh the MSI installer

**Edit**:
Why so strongly ? I'm not a perfect IT man moreover I'm from russia and don't know english well. I do not deserve minus ratings. You can stay it on zero. 
Thank you.

**Edit**:
Thank's for all responses. I appreciate it.

Comment: Did you use WMI to install your application?  If not, as noted in the linked question, the answers there will not find your application.

Comment: Oh okay, i will try to install WMI. Thank you. And sorry for my inattention. But now I'm interested in realisation of this method using ruby or py. :-)

Comment: It would be hard or impossible.  Python and Ruby are designed for Unix, not Windows.

Comment: It would would be quite easy with Python on windows, you would just need to run a command line. I can't comment on Ruby having never used it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke WMIC command in ruby or python. the process is as following:

`wmic product get name`

This command will list all the software with a formal name, for example, to the office product, the name could be 'Microsoft office 20003 Pro' or 'Microsoft office 2003 Home & Student', you can use ruby or python to filter out what is the extacly name and then execute

`wmic product where name='Microsoft office 2003 Home & Student' call uninstall`

replace 'Microsoft office 2003 Home & Student' with the application you like.

if you prefer no to execute the wmic directly , and you can import python wmi or ruby wmi instead.

Answer (score 3):

"uninstall **any** program" - evil/badly designed program may create files hidden in many places - and I see no way to create program that can find all of them. (For example: any includes all kinds of malware)

Comment: Okay. Let's I ask the question to another way. How to uninstall ordinary program which was installed thruogh the MSI installer.

Answer (score 3):

you can do plenty with msi based installation via the msiexec command. You could run\spwan this from your scripting language of choice.

```
msiexec /?
```

You'll need the package information (mainly the GUID) - this can be found here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer
```

The `Product` subkey is probably the most interesting for you.

HTH,
Matt