# How to uninstall an application using python?

Tags: python, linux, windows, macos

I'm using Spyder as an IDE on Windows 10 and I've been searching for python programs that will uninstall particular applications upon execution. So far, I have found a couple of sources:

- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978391/how-to-uninstall-any-application-using-python-or-and-ruby): The wmic command does not seem to be recognized by Spyder and returns an invalid syntax error.
- [Winapps](https://pypi.org/project/winapps/): Except the list applications command none of the other functions return any values. I tried the following code but to no avail:

```
for app in winapps.search_installed('[app_name]'):
        print(app)

winapps.uninstall('[app_name]', args=['/S'])
```

Are there any other modules and/or methods I can use to uninstall applications on my system?

Answer (score 0):

If you can call PowerShell commands with Administratos rights, maybe could you use this method:

List the installed applications:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name
```

Create a variable with informations about the app that you want to uninstall:

```
$MyApp = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "Java Auto Updater"}
```

And after, just call the Uinstall Method:

```
$MyApp.Uninstall()
```

[image]

Comment: I've trying to uninstall a couple of apps such as discord, which don't seem to appear with the Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name command, but it does not list the app. How do I overcome this issue?