# Retrieving Application's DisplayName/UninstallString from Registry Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to grab the `UninstallString` for a specific software package from
the Windows Registry.  Unfortunately, there are a number of different versions
of the package installed, so I need to query it by package name.  I've found
examples of how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25546511/1843248) and [here](https://goo.gl/k1pYYf).  I wrote a test script to
validate that I was grabbing the correct application.  This test script
**should** write the display name of the application to the console.  However,
it is instead writing a blank line.  I get the same results when I attempt to
write the `UninstallString` to the console.

```
$PATHS = @("HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
           "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
$SOFTWARE = "SOFTWARE_NAME"

ForEach ($path in $PATHS) {
    $installed = Get-ChildItem -Path $path |
                 ForEach { Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath } |
                 Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match $SOFTWARE } |
                 Select-Object -Property DisplayName,DisplayVersion,UninstallString

    ForEach ($app in $installed) {
        Write-Output "${app.DisplayName}"
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. See here: [Windows IT Pro - Auditing 32-bit and 64-bit Applications with PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/auditing-32-bit-and-64-bit-applications-powershell).

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/heaths/psmsi) is a module that gives access to a lot of MSI functionality.

Comment: @Xpw - Thanks.  Unfortunately, some of the versions weren't installed from an MSI package.  There are versions from three different major releases, at least one of which used a different installer.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - Thanks.  I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
Write-Output "${app.DisplayName}"
```

with this

```
Write-Output "$($app.DisplayName)"
```