# Create a script to uninstall and install certain programs

Tags: powershell, batch-file, installation, uninstallation

I work at a retail store, where I get new computers in all day that I need to uninstall certain programs from (like McAfee) and install certain programs on (like Java, Silverlight). Until now I have been using deCrapifier and ninite to get this done, but i was wondering if I could make a script that would automatically do this. A script that i could put on a USB and just run one time on each computer.

Could i accomplish this using a powershell script mabye?

Comment: Programs store their uninstall string under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` in the registry. Paste the `uninstallstring` value into a batch file.

Comment: The only problem is that `UninstallString` is often not correct. Next to it, both 32 and 64 bit path should be checked

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can! Provided you know the software you are going to install, and have administrative rights. It will take you some time to get it right as you need to detect each of the software separately and potentially follow different steps to uninstall, but nothing is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Many of your suggested examples (such as [Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml), and SilverLight's `/q` switch) have "Silent," or "Quiet" installers that do everything for you.  These are simple to launch from a batch file, or even via PowerShell if you'd like.

Additionally, for uninstallations, if you know the application's name as it exists on that box (exactly), [you can use PowerShell to uninstall applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113542/how-can-i-uninstall-an-application-using-powershell), as well.