# Uninstall an application using java

Tags: java, file, uninstallation

Is there any way in java by using which we can uninstall an application. I am developing an application by using which i need to check if application is installed or not. If it is installed then first i have to uninstall the application and install the newer version of it.

If it is not installed then directly go for installing.
Code what i have written is:

```
String v = "C:\\Program Files\\InstalledFile";
    File file = new File(v);
    if(file.exists()==true)
    {
        System.out.print("file exist");
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file);
        System.out.print("deleted");
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String msifile = "EP.msi";
        String para="rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL msiexec /qb /i C:\\Setup\\EP.msi REBOOT=ReallySuppress";
        run.exec(para);
    }
    else
        System.out.print("file won't exist");
```

In this code i am deleting the folder for uninstalling but that is not the solution as application still exist.

Comment: Using java for this seems like overcomplating things, since you will wind up running commands anyways. Would use powershell instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113542/how-can-i-uninstall-an-application-using-powershell

Comment: As minigeek mentioned you are going to have to do two steps ... well 3 actually.

1). Check if there is an uninstaller for the app mentioned and running that first.

2). Check the registry and remove those but you are going to have to know what registry entries are created and if you break this you can break the whole machine.

3). Remove the folder as you are currently doing.

Still not sure why you need to do it this way and this will definitely only work for Windows.

Good Luck.

Comment: @QuintonDelpeche Yes. Removing unknown registry is potentially dangerous. I added a solution to uninstall(not perfect but yet it does). Correct me if I am wrong somewhere please

Comment: This is very board with no clear question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about uninstalling(generic method) maybe someone knows.but there's a 3rd party Java API with which you can crawl the Windows registry. Every application installed in Windows is registered in registry. You can check it there . Here's sample code for firefox

**To check: particular software is installed or not ?**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;

import ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RegistryKey;
import ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RootKey;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        RegistryKey.initialize(Test.class.getResource("jRegistryKey.dll").getFile());
        RegistryKey key = new RegistryKey(RootKey.HKLM, "Software\\Mozilla");
        for (Iterator<RegistryKey> subkeys = key.subkeys(); subkeys.hasNext();) {
            RegistryKey subkey = subkeys.next();
            System.out.println(subkey.getName()); //look here for "Mozilla FireFox".here will be your body of uninstallation with some conditions
        }
    }

}
```

**This is only for Windows** for other os bash actions are required.

**How to uninstall** (only if you know uninstaller path)

```
 Process p = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\uninstall.exe"); 
 p.start();
```

Comment: jRegistryKey.dll can't be loaded as it is 32 bit... so am i suppose to downgrade my jvm from 64 bit to 32 bit

Comment: @SRISHTI yeah. You will have to move on 32bit jvm.

Comment: @SRISHTI did it help you?

Comment: but the application which i have developed is using 64 bit. So i don't think this will work for me :)

Comment: Hmm .I don't know other way :( . Hope you get your problem solved

Comment: got the solution :)

Comment: above code didn't helped me as it is for 32bit JVM and i don't think downgrading to 32-bit JVM is the solution. I have created my own batch file that helps in uninstalling :)