# Full Listing of Installed Programs using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

We've used the following command found [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113542/how-can-i-uninstall-an-application-using-powershell) to try and get a complete listing of installed programs in Windows:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product
```

However, this gives an incomplete listing of installed programs when compared with the list of installed programs in the Control panel.

Our original intention is to have a script that can interactively and eventually automatically uninstall bloatware installed on a computer. However, the command above misses a handful that we'd like to have uninstalled as well.

Is there another `Class` we can look into in order to get the complete listing? Or is there another command altogether that we can use? 
Any insight is appreciated

Comment: if you have SCCM installed, you can use the class that it adds. the other method is to check the install/uninstall items in the registry. ///// as an aside, you likely otta try to avoid `Win32_Product` when you can - it runs an integrity check on ALL the apps it know of ... and sometimes silently resets them to the default config. ouch!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Get-Package` cmdlet provides more information than the `Win32_Product` class. Here are the differences between the two on my Windows 10 system:

```
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object Name -Match TOSHIBA | Format-Table

IdentifyingNumber                      Name                        Vendor              Version      Caption
-----------------                      ----                        ------              -------      -------
{1E6A96A1-2BAB-43EF-8087-30437593C66C} TOSHIBA System Driver       Toshiba Corporation 2.00.0005    TOSHIBA System Driver
{1515F5E3-29EA-4CD1-A981-032D88880F09} TOSHIBA Audio Enhancement   Toshiba Corporation 3.0.0.9      TOSHIBA Audio Enhancement
{716C8275-A4A9-48CB-88C0-9829334CA3C5} Toshiba Quality Application TOSHIBA             1.0.9.7      Toshiba Quality Application
{E4C7D9D7-19D4-4623-AF0C-EA313C466411} Toshiba TEMPRO              Toshiba Europe GmbH 5.0.0        Toshiba TEMPRO
{72EFCFA8-3923-451D-AF52-7CE9D87BC2A1} TOSHIBA eco Utility         Toshiba Corporation 3.0.1.6403   TOSHIBA eco Utility
{B040D5C9-C9AA-430A-A44E-696656012E61} TOSHIBA System Settings     Toshiba Corporation 3.0.3.6400   TOSHIBA System Settings
{0B39C39A-3ECE-4582-9C91-842D22819A24} TOSHIBA Display Utility     Toshiba Corporation 2.0.1.0      TOSHIBA Display Utility
{EDC626BA-3E59-44C4-96B4-9066E29BF600} TOSHIBA Service Station     Toshiba Corporation 3.1.0.2      TOSHIBA Service Station
{26BB68BB-CF93-4A12-BC6D-A3B6F53AC8D9} TOSHIBA Password Utility    Toshiba Corporation 8.1.1.0      TOSHIBA Password Utility
{B507386D-1F61-4E55-B05B-F56ACB0086B3} TOSHIBA PC Health Monitor   Toshiba Corporation 5.01.02.6400 TOSHIBA PC Health Monitor
```

This one includes extra entries. You should be able to see that it includes entries from the `Programs` provider as well as the `msi` provider.

```
PS C:\> Get-Package *TOSHIBA*

Name                           Version          Source                           ProviderName
----                           -------          ------                           ------------
TOSHIBA System Driver          2.0.5            C:\Program Files (x86)\TOSHIB... msi
TOSHIBA Audio Enhancement      3.0.0.9          C:\Program Files\TOSHIBA\TOSH... msi
Toshiba Quality Application    1.0.9.7          C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshib... msi
Toshiba TEMPRO                 5.0.0            C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshib... msi
TOSHIBA eco Utility            3.0.1.6403       C:\Program Files\TOSHIBA\Teco\   msi
TOSHIBA System Settings        3.0.3.6400       C:\Program Files\TOSHIBA\Syst... msi
TOSHIBA Display Utility        2.0.1.0          C:\Program Files\Toshiba\TOSH... msi
TOSHIBA Service Station        3.1.0.2                                           msi
TOSHIBA Password Utility       8.1.1.0          C:\Program Files\Toshiba\Pass... msi
TOSHIBA Password Utility       8.1.1.0                                           Programs
TOSHIBA PC Health Monitor      5.1.2.6400       C:\Program Files\TOSHIBA\TPHM\   msi
TOSHIBA Manuals                10.20                                             Programs
TOSHIBA Recovery Media Creator 3.3.00.8003                                       Programs
```

Deleting packages from the `Programs` provider is actually harder than might sound in the first place. Entries in there will generally have an uninstall command or a quiet uninstall command but it's not guaranteed. For cases where there is a quiet uninstall string then you could do something like this:

```
function Uninstall-Program($Package) {

    $Command = foreach ($i in (0..($Package.Meta.Attributes.Keys.Count - 1))) {
        if ($Package.Meta.Attributes.Keys[$i] -eq 'QuietUninstallString') {
            $Package.Meta.Attributes.Values[$i]
        }  
    }

    Invoke-Expression "& $Command"
}
```

Then you could uninstall with:

```
$Package = Get-Package "botframework-emulator"
Uninstall-Program $Package
```

Comment: That's excellent! And certainly answers the question - however, it doesn't seem like we can use the objects returned by that method to uninstall the programs in question. Know of any way to do that last bit?

Comment: @rm-vanda could you use `Uninstall-Package -name packageName`

Comment: The `Uninstall-Package` cmdlet won't work for some entries. I've added a section for handling entries in Programs control panel.

Comment: If the package doesn't have a "QuietUninstallString", one may check each keys to find a uninstall string.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, ended up using:
`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_InstalledWin32Program`

Comment: It's a little slow, but it does show non-msi installs.