# Find msi uninstall ID asociated with program and uninstall if exist

Tags: powershell

I need to find the uninstall ID of a particular application and if it exists uninstall.

```
$MSIID = "{9F21231E-4073-4749-B331-D3206168B509}"
$FileExists = Test-Path $MSIID Test-
If ($FileExists -eq $True) {
msiexec.exe /x "{9F21231E-4073-4749-B331-D3206168B509}" /qr
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I uninstall an application using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113542/how-can-i-uninstall-an-application-using-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

The msi uninstall information can be found in the registry at the key below:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Perhaps you could find the key by display name and pull the needed info.

Another route to persue would be to query one of the [Msi api functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/installer-function-reference).

Answer (score 0):

```
get-package *pattern* | uninstall-package
```