# How can I uninstall Software Update (Programs and Features\Installed Updates) with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-installer, uninstallation

Is there a simple way of uninstalling Software UPDATES (Service Packs) listed in Programs and Features\Installed Updates with Powershell?

I am not talking about Windows Updates. But a specific software Service Pack that is listed in the same place where the win updates are.

I know how to uninstall Software that is listed in programs and features with PS
But could not figured it out how to remove the Software updates/Service Packs

this command will list all the software

`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name`

or this one

`Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate,UninstallString  | Format-Table –AutoSize`

this will remove the software but i need to remove the software Service Pack( UPDATE) only,

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -match "Software Name" 
}

$app.Uninstall()
```

I have seen that post already:
[How can I uninstall an application using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113542/how-can-i-uninstall-an-application-using-powershell)

I hope that I am clear enough, thanks

long story short is that I need a command that will list or/and remove selected software UPDATES (service packs etc), thanks

any ideas, thanks

Comment: What program's update are you trying to revert? Or are you referring to a Windows Update?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to search for any similar topics? I found like 9+

What you're looking for is this:

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -match "Software Name" 
}

$app.Uninstall()
```

or,
`$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name = 'Software Name'"`

pulled from: [How can I uninstall an application using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113542/how-can-i-uninstall-an-application-using-powershell)

Other useful links:

https://redmondmag.com/articles/2019/08/27/powershell-to-uninstall-an-application.aspx

https://www.slashadmin.co.uk/how-to-uninstall-programs-using-powershell/

All with the same conclusions of calling on the method to `.uninstall`.

for updates:

We can also use DISM for updates:

```
$SearchUpdates = dism /online /get-packages | findstr "Package_for"
$updates = $SearchUpdates.replace("Package Identity : ", "") | findstr "KBXXXXXX"
#$updates
DISM.exe /Online /Remove-Package /PackageName:$updates /quiet /norestart
```

Or native powerhsell cmdlets of `Get-Package`, and `uninstall-package`.

Made this quick script as a selection for your updates.

```
$Updates = Get-Package -Name "*Update*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
for($i=0; $i -lt $Updates.Count; $i++){
write-host "$($i): $($Updates[$i])"    
    }

$Selection = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter number of updates you would like to uninstall"
$Selection = $Selection -split " "


Foreach($Update in $Updates[$Selection]){
    Uninstall-Package -Name $Update -whatif
    }
```

`Wusa.exe` can also give you similar results if youre familiar with the syntax for it. Run `wusa.exe /?`. Ex: `Wusa /uninstall /KB:KB1234567`

Please note, ive only had real success in the past just uninstalling KBs using Wusa. DISM seems to work most of the time, but theres a lot of options available.

Comment: I know how to uninstall application, how about the applications update? the question is how to uninstall applications update only,

Comment: thanks for your answer but `dism /online /get-packages` displays only Microsoft software updates. I need to be able to list a service packs and updates for a third party software not a microsoft one, so your solution did not work for me, but thanks.